# Add command to cmd history

Tags: java, windows, command-line, cmd, process

I'm trying to run console program inside windows cmd terminal. It works. But program which I run don't added to history.

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "\"start cmd.exe /K \"" + commandLine + "\"\""};
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder().command(command);
start = builder.start();
```

I want to add ability to users to easily rerun this program lately.
Is there any way to add command to cmd.exe history?

Comment: I know that history can be *saved* with `doskey /history` but I don't believe you can edit it, otherwise people would've found solutions to problems like [this](http://serverfault.com/questions/95404/is-there-a-global-persistent-cmd-history) without add-on programs.

Comment: ServerFault duplicate: [Is there a global, persistent CMD history?](https://serverfault.com/q/95404) suggests using [clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/)

Comment: @DavidPostill I don't need persistent history. Adding command to history to only one cmd window is enough.

Comment: @turbanoff That's not possible, which is why somebody wrote clink (although it does do more than you want).

Comment: @DavidPostill I actually run program. May be is there any way to somehow `run with history` ?